# Difficulties formatting an image in a table and width

Tags: html, css, image, html-table

I am creating a table and I am having issues with a picture I am trying to add into one of the `<td>` fields. It's an icon I have and I want it to display for every record that shows up. The picture's actual size is 64px by 64px. I am trying to get it to be at 36x36, so I set my width and height to that, but it is not taking that and it cutting off the sides to it. Another issue with this table is that I have the `index_announcements_wrap` set to 100%, but when I try to add the `<td>`'s the width attribute, it messes up the picture even more, and when I add more than 40% to the message  the table doesn't expand to the right.

I created a fiddle to show everything and make it easier for everyone to see what I am doing. I want the table's columns to be 100% of the container and for it to stretch the whole width under the red bar.

https://jsfiddle.net/9w5jsd06/

Answer (score 3):

You need to account for the background size, currently it's set to cover so the image covers the space of the containers, instead use contain to display it **AS IS** and use `no-repeat` to avoid the image from repeating.

Change:

```
background-size: cover;
```

To:

```
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Here is how I would do it so it's also responsive:

```css
.wrapper {
    border: solid 1px #C0C0C0;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 10px;
    min-height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
header {
    border: solid 1px #800000;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #800000;
   color: white;
}
.warning_image {
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
}
.col-3 {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 32%;
}
@media (max-width: 640px) {
    .col-3 {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
    }
    .wrapper {
        min-height: 170px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <header>
           League Announcements:
    </header>
    <section>
        <div class="col-3">
            <img class="warning_image" src="http://png-2.findicons.com/files/icons/1609/ose_png/256/warning.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <p>FROM: <?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <p>Work for me!</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, but why is my table not going to the whole 100 width of my container div?

Comment: Look at the problem, I have just added border and `width:100%` to the table: https://jsfiddle.net/9w5jsd06/1/  - You can see it is not contained within the container. Is it a must to use a table? I would use divs which can also be responsive, using tables is really bad practice these days for almost any case.

Comment: @odedta hey i want to know that how much width does image will gets  when you use **contain ** .? can you please tell us.?

Comment: Yes, it is the exact size of the original image, you can open it in mspaint and find out.

Comment: I believe I do need to use the table. I am pulling all of the fields with a db pull with php through a while loop. I just converted it to HTML for demonstration purposes

Comment: Well, if you can fiddle with the code I suggest you implement this, non-responsive websites suffer on google's rankings these days.

Answer (score 1):

set `display: block` for your `.index_announcement_pic class`

[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/n2ryovy1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
.index_announcement_pic {
    background: url("http://png-2.findicons.com/files/icons/1609/ose_png/256/warning.png") no-repeat;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    padding: 8px;
    position: absolute;
```

replace this with your .index_announcement_pic in css it will work fine

Answer (score 1):

if you want to display your picture 36*36 then you have to do like this 
     
     http://png-2.findicons.com/files/icons/1609/ose_png/256/warning.png

instead of

```
.index_announcement_pic {
background-image: url("http://png-2.findicons.com/files/icons/1609/ose_png/256/warning.png");
width: 36px;
height: 36px;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
padding: 8px;
/*position: absolute;*/
/*margin-right: 10%;
margin-left: 10%;*/
}

<td class="index_announcement_pic"></td>
```

do this

```
 .index_announcement_pic {
width: 36px;
height: 36px;
padding: 8px;

}
  <td >
  <img src="http://png-2.findicons.com/files/icons/1609/ose_png/256/warning.png" class="index_announcement_pic">
   </td>
```

Comment: What's the point of `background-size: cover;
background-position: center;` if you used an `<img>` tag?

Comment: why you need background-size and background-position ?

Comment: There are two ways to present an image, either use the `<img>` tag or use `background: url()` property on any container.